# Javascript validate email address with website domain name in ASP.NET C#

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I've two text box in form

Example:

1. website address : http://www.domainname.com
2. email address : example.domainname.in

I want to validate email address domain name is same as web site domain name in javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Have write a below code to validate domain name

```
var websiteaddress = $('#' + $("[id$=_websiteAdd]")[0].id).val();
var emailaddress = $('#' + $("[id$=_emailaddress]")[0].id).val();
if (websiteaddress != "" && emailaddress != "") {
    var emailDomain = emailaddress.replace(/.*@/, "");
    var websiteDomain = websiteaddress .replace('http://', '').replace('https://', '').replace('www.', '').split(/[/?#]/)[0];
    if (emailDomain != websiteDomain) {
        return false;
    } 
}
return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

So you can do:

```
var email = 'something@domainname.com';
var domain = email.replace(/.*@/, "");
```

You can then compare the domain to the domain of the site.

You can do this using the code over at: http://rossscrivener.co.uk/blog/javascript-get-domain-exclude-subdomain - this is useful if you don't know where the website will be hosted or if the domain changes depending on location. If the website domain won't change then you could just hard code `websiteDomain`.

```
var websiteDomain = (function(){
   var i=0,domain=document.domain,p=domain.split('.'),s='_gd'+(new Date()).getTime();
   while(i<(p.length-1) && document.cookie.indexOf(s+'='+s)==-1){
      domain = p.slice(-1-(++i)).join('.');
      document.cookie = s+"="+s+";domain="+domain+";";
   }
   document.cookie = s+"=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;domain="+domain+";";
   return domain;
})();
```

So you could then do a check to see if:

```
domain == websiteDomain
```

Comment: I want validate any domain name entered in the both textbox. and show error msg.

Comment: Well then take the code I have provided and work it into your solution. Get the text from the text box using var email = the value from the text box; and compare it to output of the webSiteDomain....